# jquery spinner with postback event in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm using jquery spinner  in asp.net c#(not ajax). i want text box text change event in asp.net c#. which is not working with jquery spinner. Is there any way through which i can use a spinner and on every text change event of aps.net C# ``i can post-back my page  .

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="textboxModifierForcedQuantity" Visible="false" onkeypress="return false"
                                            AutoPostBack="true" Text="1" CssClass="spinnnerOptional" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure that what you are saying isn't working but you can do something like this :

on your page have a "hidden button"

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="myButton" OnClick="myButton_Click" style="display : none; visibility : hidden"></asp:Button>
```

with event where you put what you want to happen (the postback)

```
 protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
//my code to execute
        }
```

and in javascript do something like this

```
textbox.on('input',function(){
var myButton = $('#myButton');
myButton.click();
});
```

remember that this is a "not so cool" method